# Socket.IO broadcast to specific number of clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I don't know if its possible to achieve this or not, but I want to send a message to specific number of clients.

For e.g. Say I have 100 clients connected to my server. and I want to send a message in such a way that only 10 (should be able to specify in the message) out of 100 clients should receive the message and don't, or even discard it.

Just like the TTL value of a network packet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use rooms for that. When a client connect join him into a room. Then you can emit to that room.

See this link for details: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms

Comment: Thanks. I am aware about the room. see, its not like a chat room kinda app. the server needs to perform some task and it distributes among the connected clients. but how many clients will be required for what task is not fixed. that's y i want to broadcast and send number of required clients in the message itself.

Comment: In that case you'll have to keep track of the clients yourself and decide on the fly to which to emit.

Comment: i can shift the busy clients to a room so they don't get the new command. but all the free clients should not act on the new command. only few clients should start processing

Comment: hmm. That's what I am currently doing. server keeps track of all the clients and sends request to selected clients. I just thought if there is any provision for this then it would be easier. Thanks.